# How do I verify a method is not called on a mock from within the scope of one test only?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I understand that I can `verify(mock, times(0)).methodCall()` and this works when I run my one test individually.  The problem is that other tests within the file have interactions with this method and when I run all of the tests in the file I get an exception `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked:` because another test had an interaction with the mock.

Is there a way to limit the `verify()` to only count the number of interactions from within the scope of one test method instead of counting interactions across all of the tests within the file?

Comment: use reset function on the mock

Comment: How are you setting up the mock?

Comment: I was using ```any()``` to match the arguments and realized that random UUID's were being generated per test.  That meant that I could use the specific UUID in the verify() call so that interactions from other tests wouldn't be picked up.

Comment: (Typically, a good test design will set up a new mock for each different test that is run, rather than reusing the same one, e.g. the Mockito JUnit 4 rule.)

Comment: It's a spring boot project so I set it up by declaring a MockBean and Autowired the field in my test class

Comment: I think Spring by default uses a singleton pattern for the beans so that would mean the mock is the same instance for each test (not 100% sure)..  I added a reset after each test to help too.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern is: you create a new mock for each test case.

With JUnit and Mockito for example, that could look like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
  @Mock 
  Bar mockedBar;
  ...
```

Doing so will create a **new** mock instance for each of your @Test methods. When you follow that practice, there is no need to worry about "cross testcase" invocations. Because each test uses its "own" mocks.

Or the other way around: avoid to "re-use" the **same** mock objects for multiple tests.

And to be clear about that: mock objects do not know about that "test method context". They created at some point, and then method calls happen. The mock doesn't care or know "where" these calls are coming from.